# PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__) error

Tags: django

When i try:
`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)`
i get error like this:
`Traceback (most recent call last):

File "< stdin>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Run that line of code via an actual module instead of in the Python REPL.

Comment: I try this clearly in bash:  
`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)`  
and now i get:  
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`  
I still don't know some significant things about bash, i think.. Is there any solution which You could provide?

Comment: You *really* need to stop writing Python code at the bash prompt. And while you're at it, read the tutorial. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to use `__file__` from your interpreter, no `__file__` is defined. This is the intended behavior. `__file__` is an attribute of modules. [**`Here`**](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=12785) is a discussion about the subject.

*You can test by doing this:*

```
~$ echo "print __file__" > test.py
~$ python test.py
test.py
```

**`__file__` works in from within modules.**

*Now from the interpreter:*

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.0+ (r27:82500, Sep 15 2010, 18:04:55) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print __file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

*`__file__` is not defined*

```
>>> import test
test.pyc
>>> print __file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

*`__file__` is not defined*

```
>>> print test.__file__
test.pyc
>>>
```

*`__file__` is defined for the test module*

Comment: That explain something to me, but i still don't know what is the solution for my problem. I don't wanna reading python book, I just need to make small django-powerade project with two applications in one folder. It must be two applications in one folder. But thanks for some directions.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this in your settings.py :

```
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```